# Отследить клик вне компонента vue

Tags: vue.js

Конкретный кейс - схлопнуть `dropdown`, если был произведен клик за его пределами. Задача на ванильном `js` тривиальная, но во `Vue.js` превратилось в гемор.

Пробовал `vue-clickaway`, но он отслеживает клик в родительском компоненте. То есть, имея компонент `dropdown` внутри `menu-element`, событие, установленное на `dropdown` (`v-on-clickaway`) срабатывает только при нажатии на `menu-element`.

Пробовал кастомные директивы, но их довольно сложно писать (до этого не доводилось) - срабатывают с ошибками, и так же, как и пример выше, срабатывают только в рамках родительского компонента.

Забавно, но даже в примерах на [vuejsexamples.com](https://vuejsexamples.com/) во всех `dropdown` эта ситуация никак не обрабатывается.

Comment: `document.addEventListener('click', closeDropdown)`. Незабудбте удалить обработчик в `beforeDestroy`

Comment: Приведите код в снипет.

Comment: Подобное можно на потере фокуса отлавливать `@blur="onBlur"`.